# How correctly replace string

Tags: c#

In my code I find all matches elements and replace it with special values.

```
Regex imgRule = new Regex("img id=\\\".+?\\\"");
                    MatchCollection matches = imgRule.Matches(content.Value);
                    string result = null;
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                        result = match.Value;

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        var firstOrDefault = node.ListImages.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (firstOrDefault != null)
                        {
                            var htmlWithImages = content.Value.Replace(result, string.Format("img src='{0}' class='newsimage' width='300'", firstOrDefault.ImageUrlId));
                            node.Content = htmlWithImages;
                        }
                    }
```

But, my code is wrong because if  there is more than one match it replace only the last one, how can I correct my code for replace all matches in text?

Comment: What is the type of `content`? Where is it declared? What is the type of `node`? Where is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing curly braces around the body of your for loop. Without the curly braces the only line that gets executed multiple times is the first one.

Try this instead:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{                                    // added curly brace here
    result = match.Value;

    if (result != null)
    {
        var firstOrDefault = node.ListImages.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
        {
            var htmlWithImages = content.Value.Replace(result,
                string.Format("img src='{0}' class='newsimage' width='300'",
                              firstOrDefault.ImageUrlId));
            node.Content = htmlWithImages;
        }
    }
}                                    // added curly brace here
```

I would also like to add two further points:

- There is a method called `Regex.Replace` that you can use instead of first finding the strings you want to replace using a regex, and then using `string.Replace`.
- If you are trying to parse HTML it would be better to use a HTML parser. Take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) to see if it could be an easier way to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, in any case the main question is: at first time I replace content.Value with first match and then I replace content.Value fith second match, and the first replace is not save

Comment: @revolutionkpi: One strange thing about your code is that you are reading from `content.Value` and assigning to `node.Content`. Are you sure that when you assign to `node.Content` that the changes are visible in `content.Value`? I think it would make more sense to read the content out of the document and into a plain string, make the desired replacements on the string (`s = s.Replace(...);`), then reassign the final result back to the document at the end (not inside the loop). But you really should be using HTML Agility Pack for this sort of thing. It will make your life much easier.

Comment: @revolutionkpi: By the way, my answer was actually to your "main" question. If you think my answer was not answering your question then I think you may have either misread or else misunderstood my answer. It's also possible that you have not *one*, but *multiple* errors in your code. Then I suggest you fix them one by one, and don't be discouraged that fixing one error doesn't immediately solve all your problems. Sometimes you need to take many small steps to reach your final destination.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing a set of brackets around your loop...

Only this line gets looped. That's why your code only updates the last entry, as result is set to the last item in the collection (on the last iteration of the foreach)

```
         foreach (Match match in matches) 
                      result = match.Value;
```

**Corrected code**

```
  Regex imgRule = new Regex("img id=\\\".+?\\\"");
                        MatchCollection matches = imgRule.Matches(content.Value);
                        string result = null;
                        foreach (Match match in matches) {
                            result = match.Value;

                           if (result != null)
                           {
                               var firstOrDefault = node.ListImages.FirstOrDefault();
                               if (firstOrDefault != null)
                               {
                                   var htmlWithImages = content.Value.Replace(result,    string.Format("img src='{0}' class='newsimage' width='300'", firstOrDefault.ImageUrlId));
                                   node.Content = htmlWithImages;
                               }
                           }   
                        }
```

Comment: thanks, but when I replace string with the second match the first is no save, so in result there is only the last replacement

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    result = match.Value;

    if (result != null)
    {
        var firstOrDefault = node.ListImages.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstOrDefault != null)
        {
            var htmlWithImages = content.Value.Replace(result, string.Format("img src='{0}' class='newsimage' width='300'", firstOrDefault.ImageUrlId));
            node.Content = htmlWithImages;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the Regex.Replace method not simplify what you're trying to accomplish?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.71).aspx